# Efficient pivot/data comparison

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA, however I have a programming background. I'm writing VBA to open two excel workbooks, copy the pivot tables and paste special the values into a staging workbook. From there, I need to compare the pivot data and output the differences. However, I'm not sure where to go from there.

**Sample Data**

Pivot 1

```
Sum of Fruits          YearMon
Category       Group   201205 201206 201207 201208 201209 ... 201401
Apples         Green                    1.3    2.1    3.0 ...
               Red                      1.0    1.5    2.0 ...
Apples Total                            ..     ..     ..  ...
Berries        Straw        1      1    1.1    2.0    2.1 ...
               Black        1      1    1.0    0.9    0.9 ...
Berroes Total                           ..     ..     ..  ...
```

Pivot 2

```
Sum of Fruits          YearMon
Category       Group   201206 201207 201208 201209 201210 ... 201402
Apples         Green                    1.5    2.3    3.2 ...
               Red                      0.8    1.3    1.9 ...
               Yellow              1    0.9    0.9      1 ...
Apples Total                            ..     ..     ..  ...
Berries        Straw        1      1    1.3    1.8    2.1 ...
               Black        1      1    0.9    0.8    0.8 ...
Berroes Total                           ..     ..     ..  ...
```

Desired Result *(Pivot 2 - Pivot 1)*

```
Sum of Fruits          YearMon
Category       Group   201205 201206 201207 201208 201209 201210 ... 201402
Apples         Green                          -0.6   -0.7        ...
               Red                            -0.7   -0.7        ... 
Apples Total                            ..     ..     ..         ...
Berries        Straw               0   -0.1   -0.7   -0.3        ...
               Black               0      0      0   -0.1        ...
Berries Total                           ..     ..     ..         ...
```

My first impulse is to put `YearMon` and `Group` into arrays based on each `Category`, then looping through them to remove attributes which don't exist in both pivots (ie. yellow apples don't exist in Pivot 1, and there is no data for `201402`). I would then loop through each group and do the calculation. This sounds too messy.

I'm currently thinking to create a range for `YearMon` and `Group`, then looping through the range, vertically and horizontally, for each `Category` to compare the values. I'm not sure how to exactly find where each `Category` stops, or whether I could perhaps use `VLOOKUP`? Or is there some simpler way to compare two pivots?

**Update 1**

The majority of the comments recommend that I try to use the source data behind the pivot to accomplish this task. I'm able to get the data and following the scheme above, which looks like:

Data 1

```
Category Group YearMon Value
Apples   Green 201207  1.3
Apples   Green 201208  2.1
Apples   Green 201209  3.0
Apples   Red   201207  1.0
Apples   Red   201208  1.5
Apples   Red   201209  2.0
Berries  Straw 201205  1.0
Berries  Straw 201206  1.0
Berries  Straw 201207  1.1
Berries  Straw 201208  2.0
Berries  Straw 201209  2.1
Berries  Black 201205  1.0
Berries  Black 201206  1.0
Berries  Black 201207  1.0
Berries  Black 201208  0.9
Berries  Black 201209  0.9
```

Data 2

```
Category Group YearMon Value
Apples   Green  201208  1.5
Apples   Green  201209  2.3
Apples   Green  201210  3.2
Apples   Red    201208  0.8
Apples   Red    201209  1.3
Apples   Red    201210  1.9
Apples   Yellow 201207  1.0
Apples   Yellow 201208  0.9
Apples   Yellow 201209  0.9
Apples   Yellow 201210  1.0
Berries  Straw  201206  1.0
Berries  Straw  201207  1.0
Berries  Straw  201208  1.3
Berries  Straw  201209  1.8
Berries  Straw  201210  2.1
Berries  Black  201206  1.0
Berries  Black  201207  1.0
Berries  Black  201208  0.9
Berries  Black  201209  0.8
Berries  Black  201210  0.8
```

After attempting `SUMIFS` as suggested below, it appears that I would need to specify each criteria (Category, Group, YearMon) for each data set to do the comparison. Perhaps there is some other functionality that would work?

**Update 2**

Another suggestion was to combine the data sets to calculate the difference from in a pivot. After combining these two data sets, I can't seem to figure out a way to do the difference calculation without including another column that identifies each data set (1 or 2). From there I'm able to do the comparison. Am I doing something incorrectly?

**Update 3**

Following an answer below, I've simply negated the values of the second data set to get the difference.

Comment: Can you get at the data set behind your pivot tables? If so you can use `SUMIFS` to get the totals for each grouping, then subtract the two groups. Just another approach... may not be feasible with your situation.

Comment: I would agree that getting to the data behind the pivot tables would make it easier.  Combine both data sets into one long data set and multiply the amounts in one set by -1, then do a new pivot table based on this combined data set.  You pivot table would then show the difference between the two automatically and you'd still have the ability to rearrange/slice & dice the pivot table any way you wanted.

Comment: Rob G's solution is clearly the right way to do this. Learn how to do that and you'll become better at excel

Comment: @d--b I don't think that kind of knowledge/method/idea is specific to excel. Although, I agree it is a good option for the the OP and probably the easiest way to do what the OP is trying to do. Although it is not clear from his question if he has access to the actual pivot tables and thus the original data(or just the pivot table values).

Comment: @Stephan1010: true, but you can always go back to the original table by putting all the fields in the row section and display the pivot in tabular form without any total.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've gotten access to the raw data and posted some sample data. Playing around with `SUMIFS`, it seems as though I need to iterate through each Category, Group and YearMon to get the `SUM` of Value.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the great suggestion. I've stacked both raw data sets and created a pivot based off those. However, I can't seem to find a value to calculate the difference. It seems if I add another column that identifies the dataset (ie. 1 or 2), then I can compare to the next/previous. Is this how I should be approaching this?

Comment: Hello, like Rob G suggested, if you want to use his method, you need to multiply all the values in one of your two data sets by negative 1. Then you can combine your two data sets into one and make a pivot table based on that data. This will give you the "difference" between the two data sets(summarized in the pivot table).

Comment: @Stepan1010 Thanks for that tip. I will try this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate what I was suggesting. Take your Data 1, multiply all amounts by -1, and add Data 2 to it, gives you:

[image: Combined Data]

Doing a pivot table based on that combined data gives you:

[image: New Pivot Table]

The pivot table SUM does the difference for you, for whatever row/column combinations you want.  The trick is the multiplying one Data set by -1

*Trick: Type -1 in a new cell, Ctrl-C on that cell, then select all the values in Data 1 group, then do Paste Special and select 'Multiply'*

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
=INDEX($B$11:$H$14,MATCH($A18,$A$11:$A$14,0),MATCH(B$17,$B$10:$H$10,0))-(INDEX($B$3:$H$7,MATCH($A18,$A$3:$A$7,0),MATCH(B$17,$B$2:$H$2,0)))
```

I don't think there are any built in functions to combine pivot tables. So generally the issue does not seem to be specific to pivot tables - but rather just how to combine/subtract/add two seperate tables of data.

[image: SubtractTwoTables]

Not sure if you were looking for a VBA solution, but that is one way to do it with an (extremely verbose) spreadsheet formula. You could also probably use SUMIF formulas like Scott mentioned or just work with the orginal data. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into this and follow up soon.

Comment: This method requires you to create your own template for the result table with all the headers and row labels you are going to need (copy/paste unique values would probably be helpful here).

Comment: +1 but the formula would be simpler if it was split up and added to say a row above,  and a column next to the Result Table - more readable and auditable.